# How can I use php to open a random file?

Tags: php, html, forms

I would like to know how to get a random file in one directory and open it. This should be performed with a button, that launches a php script. Example:

HTML:

```
<form action="./generate.php" method="get">
    <span>arg1</span><input type="checkbox" name="level_arg1">
    <span>arg2</span><input type="checkbox" name="arg2_" >
    <span>arg3</span><input type="checkbox" name="arg3_">
    <input type="submit" id="generate" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$class = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
$rand = array_rand($class);
file_get_contents("http://localhost/class/" . $rand . ".html");
?>
```

I tried the above, but was given the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$rand' (T_VARIABLE) in <directory>\generate.php on line 3
```

Anyway I could make this work?

Comment: Easily - by inserting a semicolon at the end of the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a semi-colon at the end of your first line:

`$class = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);`